# How to get non-alphabetical separator char from string

Tags: regex, string, groovy, character, special-characters

I have a situation where I want to get separator char from the given string like as below :-

```
String str1 = "saurabh|om|anurag|abhishek|jitendra"

String str2 = "amit,ankur,sumit,aniket,suheel"

String str3 = "aj-kumar-manav-lalit-gaurav"

-------
```

In above strings I want to get separator char as :-

```
String separatorStr1 = "|"
String separatorStr2 = ","
String separatorStr3 = "-"
```

**Note** :- *separator char always will be non-alphabetical in string*

Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: get second character of each string lol

Comment: @xenteros No, this is situation only, Not sure the length of string before separator ...the string could be `abb|bs|csaf|dwet|erww`

Comment: @xenteros see updated question..:)

Comment: Not putting it as answer, as it is java, not groovy, but something like `str.chars().filter(c -> !Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c)).findAny()` should be good enough.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski could you please elaborate your comment..I'm running your solution but i'm getting optional object.. how to get char from that??.. you can post it as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `groovy` `regexp` and `find` ([^\w] is any non-alphanumeric character)

```
def getSeparator = { str ->
    str.find(~/[^\w]/)
}

String str1 = "saurabh|om|anurag|abhishek|jitendra"
String str2 = "amit,ankur,sumit,aniket,suheel"
String str3 = "aj-kumar-manav-lalit-gaurav"

assert getSeparator(str1) == '|'
assert getSeparator(str2) == ','
assert getSeparator(str3) == '-'
```

Comment: Great.. work well!!!...but could you tell me using regexp is good enough??

Comment: Usually regexp is no too readable, but for this example it is quite simple and shows how simple regular expressions are in groovy using the `~/.../` syntax

Answer (score 1):

Why is a `-` separator of `str3`? It could be `a` as well.

Assuming separator must be non-alphabetical loop through characters and look for first non-alphabetical character.

In future questions try to avoid other users guessing what you mean - try to define the subject of a topic.

Comment: thanks for you suggestion, updated my question as well.. but you can point it out by providing comment not actually by answer.. thnaks..:)

Comment: If it's non-alphabetical, then my solution might work.

Answer (score 1):

By [xenteros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4723795/xenteros) suggestion I have achieved this by following way :-

```
String str1 = "saurabh|om|anurag|abhishek|jitendra"
String str2 = "amit,ankur,sumit,aniket,suheel"
String str3 = "aj-kumar-manav-lalit-gaurav"

String separatorStr1 = str1.toCharArray().find { !Character.isLetterOrDigit(it) }
String separatorStr2 = str2.toCharArray().find { !Character.isLetterOrDigit(it) }
String separatorStr3 = str3.toCharArray().find { !Character.isLetterOrDigit(it) }

assert separatorStr1 == '|'
assert separatorStr2 == ','
assert separatorStr3 == '-'
```

Comment: @xenteros, yeah because suggestion is yours...but yet I'm looking for more groovier solution...:)